# What layout name / type and configuration in cytoscape.js I shod use to achieve the layout in the picture below

Tags: cytoscape.js

What layout name / type and configuration in [cytoscape.js](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js)  I shod use to achieve the layout in the picture below 
Like Horizontal Tree....

[image: What layout name / typea and configuration in cytoscape.js I shod use to achieve the layout in the picture below]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dagre with a left-to-right alignment:

Extension : https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-dagre

Demo with top-to-bottom : http://js.cytoscape.org/demos/e52c2fbc0b09edd6ec46/

```
layout: {
    name: 'dagre',
    rankDir: "RL",
}
```

Comment: Another quest if you don't mind for directions :-) 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36823826/what-layout-name-type-and-configuration-in-cytoscape-js-i-shod-use-to-achieve