# What layout name / type and configuration in cytoscape.js I shod use to achieve the layout of 2 types of entities that appear as a Circle in each Side

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

What layout name / type and configuration in [cytoscape.js](http://js.cytoscape.org/) I shod use to achieve the layout in the picture below, circular & with 3 levels

[image: What layout name / type and configuration in cytoscape.js I shod use to achieve the layout in the picture below]

There are 2 types of entities that appear as a Circle in each Side , 1 type on the left in circular structure and the second one on the right in circular structure.

This is Example Data Structure :

```
var Nodes=[
  {
    "data": {
      "id": "application1003",
      "type": "application",
      "label": "dataWarehouse",
      "selected": true
    }
  },
  {
    "data": {
      "id": "sub1002",
      "type": "sub",
      "label": "DW_accounts",
      "selected": false,
      "isLeaf": false
    }
  },
  {
    "data": {
      "id": "sub1002topic1002",
      "type": "topic-3leaf",
      "label": "Accounts",
      "selected": false,
      "isLeaf": true
    }
  },
  {
    "data": {
      "id": "sub1004",
      "type": "sub",
      "label": "DW_Campaigns",
      "selected": false,
      "isLeaf": false
    }
  },
  {
    "data": {
      "id": "sub1004topic1101",
      "type": "topic-3leaf",
      "label": "campaigns2",
      "selected": false,
      "isLeaf": true
    }
  }
] 



var Edges=
        [
  {
    "data": {
      "source": "sub1002",
      "target": "application1003"
    }
  },
  {
    "data": {
      "source": "sub1002topic1002",
      "target": "sub1002"
    }
  },
  {
    "data": {
      "source": "sub1004",
      "target": "application1003"
    }
  },
  {
    "data": {
      "source": "sub1004topic1101",
      "target": "sub1004"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`concentric`](http://js.cytoscape.org/#layouts/concentric) layout with start and end angles, but you'd have to set the level values based on a prior [BFS](http://js.cytoscape.org/#eles.breadthFirstSearch) traversal (i.e. store the the level in `scratch()` or `data()` and use that value in `concentric`).

The levels in a concentric layout are based on arbitrary, dev-specified values -- unlike DAG layouts which assume traversal levels -- so you'll need this extra BFS step.

Comment: Not sure I got all the picture... 
How i can position the main item in the middle... ?

Do you have any close to that example ?

Comment: Either manually or with level/radius 0

Comment: What custom layout you will recommend to read / understand  to get the skills  to write my own that do those 2 steps that you had described ?

Comment: So you suggest to create a new layout or adjust the existing one ?

Comment: Use the concentric layout, as I suggested

Comment: Yes, but how I can modify it's behavior... any demo on how it's done in other layouts that execute the layout and then modify the existing results.

Comment: It's really just a matter of using nodes.positions(), node.position(), or eles.layout() in combination with each other or one after another.  Each layout has its options documented that allow you to customise the parameters of the layout.